# how do I link the posts and the comments table using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using PHP & MySQL to build a social media application, I am quite new at this so I wanted to know how do I link the comments with Its own respective post? I have 2 MySQL tables and here is the SQL for them,

table posts:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(3000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `postBy` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `postDate` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

table comments:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `commentBy` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `commentDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I don't really have a PHP query right now because I don't know how to link the two tables and then how to display the comments respectively for every post, I have no idea how to do this at all.

So can someone please explain how to do this? and please explain everything step by step as I am new.

Also, I am new at this platform so If I broke a rule while asking this question please don't mind and let me know what I did wrong and I'll fix that.

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Right now comments and posts are not related. In your comments table you'd need a column `post_id` (or something) that "links"/relates a comment to an `id` in your posts table

Comment: You also likely should have your `id` columns auto increment and make your `postDate` a `datetime` datatype.

Comment: @user3783243 Ok I get it but DateTime format always gives the wrong date I was thinking to change the commentDate to a varchar as well and insert the date & time using PHP, should I do that?

Comment: @Stranger Yes Of course you should do this to make your user's see correct time. You can add your own date time using [php date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method.

Comment: @Vinayak What??? Why should the OP not use datetime for a date time field?

Comment: @Stranger What does it give? How are you writing it?

Comment: @user3783243 I am using the now() function while the column having DateTime format and the time shows 4 hours late as the time right now I think the DateTime format does not support my region or something and also using PHP date functions as mentioned by Vinayak also works so Imma stick to that, Is there any reason I shouldn't? or do using PHP date functions have any security flaw?

Comment: @Stranger You need to set the timezone of your SQL to match your application server's timezone. You won't be able to use any date comparison functions in your DB if you use `varchar`. It will just be a string.

Comment: @user3783243 Nah I am good as long as it doesn't cause any security violence as we have our own auto-timezone management system so we don't need to do that, also I contacted the manager and he told me that I should use PHP date time function and save the time in the database in order for our auto-timezone management system to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Good Evening

First of all you should have a one more column in your comments table which stores the id of the post and you can name it as post_id or something you wish.

*Because if you don't have access to your post How can you able to access comments*

**Like if the post id is 1 so your comments table should have a column which stores the value of it**

So if anyone adds a comment you can access the post id and add it to your comments table.

Now if you want to access the comments you can simply access these by the post id.

Like -

```
$id = post_id ; //here post id comes
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id' ";
```

> **I would also like to give you an idea so you can access your posts and comments easily**

You can make a file **post.php**

And from the home page where you are showing the post's you can add a link to every post to the file **post.php** with post id as a get parameter.

Like -

```
<a href="posts.php?post-id=2" > Post Name  </a>
```

And then you can access the post id very easily using get parameter like this on post.php -

```
$post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con , $_GET['post-id']); //$con is connection to database
```

And now you can very easily access the post and comments

> Hope you understood